# How to handle all possible errors cleanly when using HTTP conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have some code that looks like this:

```
retryOnTimeout :: IO a -> IO a
retryOnTimeout action = catch action $ \ResponseTimeout -> 
                            do putStrLn "Timed out. Trying again."
                               threadDelay 5000000
                               action
```

The problem is that there are a lot of other constructors of HttpException, and I would like to generally keep trying again, regardless of exactly what the error is. Now if I replace `ResponseTimeout` with `_` then I will get a compile error because it cannot deduce the type of the exception.

I don't really want to provide a type signature for the exception handler either.

I know it's not *much* duplication, but adding a case for `_` feels wrong because it's like saying: if the exception is ResponseTimeout then do x, but if the exception is anything else *do exactly the same thing*. Is there a concise way to use a wildcard but still let the compiler know which type it is?

Comment: How about `catch action $ \ (_ :: HttpException) -> do ...`? Might need `ScopedTypeVariables` turned on to compile.

Comment: Aaahhh! ScopedTypeVariables! GHC even suggested that, but I thought it was erroneous because I never saw that exact usage of the extension before. Please add as an answer so I can accept, thanks!

Comment: You could also write `\~ResponseTimeout -> ` which ties down the type without doing any actual match as `~` is a lazy pattern. However, `ScopedTypeVariables` is a much better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't care about the exception value it's totally fine to use `_` but you'll need to use `ScopedTypeVariables` or a let clause to specify the type you want.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

retryOnTimeout :: IO a -> IO a
retryOnTimeout action = catch action $ \ (_ :: HttpException) -> do
  putStrLn "Timed out. Trying again."
  threadDelay 5000000
  action
```